# Unable to set the panel location to the current mouse position inside splitContainer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have panel1 in my form, i set the visible property to `panel1.Visible=false;` I want to show this panel wherever i click on the screen.

I need to grab the current mouse location and then display the `panel1` where the top-left corner must be in the same point as the mouse cursor !

Sorry for being so beginner but i really stuck on how to do it.

Code that i tried :

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 {
     panel1.Location = e.Location;
     panel1.Show();
 }
```

Comment: And whats wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: the panel appears but on different locations ! Not the top-left of panel on the same point as my cursor @Blachshma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might this will be your guide to your task, just use the [`.PointToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) and [`.GetCellDisplayRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcelldisplayrectangle%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
        var cellRectangle = dataGridView1.PointToScreen(
            dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location);
        panel1.Location = new Point(cellRectangle.X + 50, cellRectangle.Y - 175);
        panel1.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I can recognize your problem you should use PointToScreen function - more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx)